# Origin and destination with R

Tags: r, list

I have a table listing the place where an Id stopped (sorting by time).

```
df <- structure(list(Location = c("enter_Skagen", "Nordjyllands-Vaerket", 
                                  "exit_Skagen", "enter_Skagen", "Nordjyllands-Vaerket", "exit_Skagen", 
                                  "enter_Skagen", "Nordjyllands-Vaerket", "exit_Skagen", "enter_Skagen", 
                                  "Nordjyllands-Vaerket", "exit_Skagen", "enter_Skagen", "Nordjyllands-Vaerket", 
                                  "exit_Skagen", "enter_Skagen", "Aarhus", "Fredericia", "Copenhagen", 
                                  "exit_Skagen"), Ship = c(8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 
                                                           8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 
                                                           8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8131180L, 8201674L, 8201674L, 8201674L, 
                                                           8201674L, 8201674L)), .Names = c("Location", "Id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(61702L, 
                                                                                                                                                     61698L, 61699L, 61703L, 61704L, 61705L, 61700L, 61707L, 61711L, 
                                                                                                                                                     61697L, 61701L, 61710L, 61708L, 61709L, 61706L, 63055L, 63053L, 
                                                                                                                                                     63045L, 63103L, 63159L))
```

I would like to have a matrix counting the number of moves between the different locations per Id. As a first step, I tried to edit the table to have two column `from` and `to`.

I tried to split by Id and then to transform with the following lines:

```
spl <- split(df, df$Id)
move.spl <- lapply(spl, function(x) {
  ret <- data.frame(from=head(df$Location, -1), to=tail(df$Location, -1),
                    #year=ceiling((head(x$year, -1)+tail(x$year, -1))/2),
                    #id=head(x$id, -1),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
moves <- rbindlist(move.spl)
```

It gives as output:

```
> moves
                    from                   to
 1:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
 2: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
 3:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
 4:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
 5: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
 6:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
 7:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
 8: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
 9:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
10:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
11: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
12:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
13:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
14: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
15:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
16:         enter_Skagen               Aarhus
17:               Aarhus           Fredericia
18:           Fredericia           Copenhagen
19:           Copenhagen          exit_Skagen
20:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
21: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
22:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
23:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
24: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
25:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
26:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
27: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
28:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
29:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
30: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
31:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
32:         enter_Skagen Nordjyllands-Vaerket
33: Nordjyllands-Vaerket          exit_Skagen
34:          exit_Skagen         enter_Skagen
35:         enter_Skagen               Aarhus
36:               Aarhus           Fredericia
37:           Fredericia           Copenhagen
38:           Copenhagen          exit_Skagen
                    from                   to
```

On the line 15, it should not be like this because the id is different. 
After line 15, it is doing well for the next Id but after it goes completely bananas.

(than I create the matrix of origin / destination with

```
a <-    table(moves$from, moves$to)
  a <- data.table(a)
  colnames(a) <- c("from","to", "N")

  # create matrix
  matrix <- dcast(a, from ~to, value.var = "N")
```

but this is a final step)

the results of the `moves` are a bit odd. I am not sure that this working and splitting per Id I guess it just taking the list as a whole but not checking per Id.

Is it possible to have a better result taking into account the Id?

Comment: What is your expected output?  After you split by 'Id', why you are using `head(df$Location, -1)`?  Should that be `head(x$Location, -1)`

Comment: If you are using data.table, `setDT(df)[, .(from = Location[-.N], to = Location[-1L]) , Id]` or `dcast(setDT(df)[, .(from = Location[-.N], to = Location[-1L]) , Id], from ~ to, value.var = "to", length)`

Comment: Thanks @Akrun, I edited my post. `It seems that with setDT(df)[, .(from = Location[-.N], to = Location[-1L]) , Id]` it looks better. I am testing on a sample and I let you know.

Comment: @Akrun, if I understand well, I don´t need to split per Id if I use `setDT(df)[, .(from = Location[-.N], to = Location[-1L]) , Id]`, right?

Comment: by = Id is doing this for each Id.  I don't know about your expected output

Comment: This is the output I want: counting for each Id. Thanks